# Mostrar barra de menú al iniciar sesion

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

tengo una pagina iniciar que es un logIn y necesito iniciar sesión y que cuando cargue la vista me muestre la barra de menú.

StartUp

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<HotelPrimaveraContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
      
    services.AddControllersWithViews();

    services.AddSession();

    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "LogIn";
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None;
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20); 
            options.LoginPath = "/Reserva/Index"; 
        });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  
    app.UseSession();
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Layot:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-transparent border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container">

            <label class="brand">
                <a class="navbar-brand">
                    <img src="~/img/logo21.png" />
                </a>
            </label>


            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Inicio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Cliente" asp-action="Index">Cliente</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Empleado" asp-action="Index">Empleado</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Habitacion" asp-action="Index">Habitación</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Reserva" asp-action="Index">Reservas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="ServicioAdicional" asp-action="Index">Servicios Adicionales</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Empleado" asp-action="Logout">Cerrar sesion</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

}
```

Comment: Basta con verificar que haz hecho login correctamente y actualizar la vista de acuerdo a esto.

Comment: Lo intente hacer con una cookie pero no me la muestra nunca cuando pongo la condicion en el Layout: